# Lua os.date() - What's the difference between *t and !*t

Tags: lua

The first argument passed to os.date() is the format string. I've seen people use `*t` and `!*t` as the format string.

Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lua [ref manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date.) describes this:

> If format starts with '!', then the date is formatted in Coordinated Universal Time

These two examples show the difference:

```
local t = os.date( "!%a %b %d, %H:%M")
print(t) -- Thu Oct 25, 04:01 (current UTC)

local t = os.date( "%a %b %d, %H:%M")
print(t) -- Thu Oct 25, 12:01
```